# Ubuntu, opencv and linking

Tags: ubuntu, opencv, linker

I installed Ubuntu a few days ago, and used apt-get to install build_essentials, opencv, highgui, etc.  g++ is 4.6.1, opencv appears to be 2.1.0..  I didn't build opencv from source..

We have some software that uses opencv functionality.  Let's pretend the source files are named a.cpp and b.cpp.  I compile to a.o and b.o and then put those into a .so library (call it libab.so).

Finally, there's a file with main in it (call it z.cpp).  I try to build an executable from it, but I get a ton of "undefined reference" errors to cv:: stuff.   My link line looks something like this:

```
g++ -fPIC -g z.cpp -L../lib -lab -lml -lcvaux -lhighgui -lcv -lcxcore -o z.out
```

then I get the undefined reference errors (all of which are to cv:: stuff).

The interesting part is if I link directly with my .o files, it builds just fine.  So this:

```
g++ -fPIC -g z.cpp a.o b.o -lml -lcvaux -lhighgui -lcv -lcxcore -o z.out
```

works.

Everything I've read seems to imply this is likely a link-line-ordering issue, but I have tried all ordering permutations and get the same problem, so I really don't think its my issue, but I could still be wrong.  Anyone have any ideas how I can get this to build with my library, and why it would act differently if I build with the complete set of .o files that are in the library successfully, but can't build with the library itself?

Comment: Ok, so this isn't really a "solution", but I ended up installing opencv 2.3.1 from source - also had to install ffmpeg (v0.8 specifically!) and now everything works.  So, it clearly had something to do with the opencv build that I got with apt-get.  I haven't tried this, but I'm guessing I could have installed 2.1 from source and it would have worked too.  Still not sure why compiling with the library vs the .o's would be a problem, but things are working now, so....

Answer (score 17):

You can pass the following flag to g++:

```
`pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

For example:

```
g++ myprogram.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv` -o myprogram
```

pkg-config give to the compiler the information about the library for you.

You can look at:

/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc

This file contains all the relevant information for compilation:

```
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir_old=${prefix}/include/opencv
includedir_new=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenCV
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 2.3.1
Libs: -L${libdir} -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann
Cflags: -I${includedir_old} -I${includedir_new}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing, which is why I don't think it was an opencv or library naming issue.  I didn't show it in my post for clarity, but since I got the libs directly from pkg-config, I was pretty sure I was using the correct ones.  I'm going to add a comment to my original question for the "resolution"..

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you are linking with the older C libraries. Today's OpenCV link commands would be more like: `-lopencv_core -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui...`.

I usually link with the core module first, since order does matter, then follow the alphabet order (to be sure that I don't forget a module).

**-- EDIT --**

Did you try to put the -lab after opencv libs ? This may do the trick, since the libraries are linked in the order of the command line.

Comment: Are those for opencv2.1.0?  I know they changed it, but I got those libs from "pkg-config opencv --libs" so I assume they're the right ones - also it links fine when I link with the .o files, so it seems likek those have got to be right.. I'll check for existence of libs named the new way..

Comment: The actual production release is 2.3.x, and 2.4.0 is in beta. Ubunutu seems to be quite late on the versions. Anyway, as far as I can remember, even if some new modules were added along time, the libopencv_core, libopencv_highui, libopencv_imgproc... had this name pattern in 2.x releases.

Comment: Interesting..  I don't have any files named "libopencv*". The files in /usr/lib are named "libcv.so.2.1.0" "libcvaux.so.2.1.0" etc..  At this point, I may be forced to get 2.3.x and build from source and se if it helps.  This just doesn't seem like an opencv issue though, given that I can build just fine when I link with the .o files from my source rather than the .so that was built from my source..

Comment: I might be mistaken then, and this organization came with OpenCV 2.2. I updated my answer though, maybe this helps you. But yes, I would recommend you to use a more recent snapshot.

Comment: Yep, I tried different orderings and nothing helped.  As I commented on my original post, I ended up installing opencv v2.3.1 from source and the problem went away.  Not sure why but I guess the main thing is that it works now.  Thanks for all the suggestions..