# How do I link the library containing 'pyrUp' for opencv?

Tags: opencv, linker, g++

I've been compiling and linking opencv code successfully for the past few days with the following command:

```
g++ motion.cpp -o motion `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

But I have recently added a call to the `pyrUp()` function:

```
pyrUp( in, out, Size( 640,480 ) );
```

Now when I compile I get the following linker error:

```
motion.cpp:(.text+0x1385): undefined reference to `cv::pyrUp(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::Size_<int> const&, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I missing? Is there an alternative function I should be using? I thought I was already linking in all of the opencv libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it the pkg-config([REF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415236/ububtu-opencv-and-linking)) loads a config file from here /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc which contains a number of settings.

You may have to add the specific lib that contains pyrup on to the end of this line

```
Libs: -L${libdir} -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
-lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann
```

*The opencv.pc file may also reside in a different folder from that listed above.*

It may also be that your using a version of openCV that doesn't come with a precompiled library. In which case you would have to add the source of the .cpp file for this function as an argument. I'm not actually sure how to do this as i use an ID and not the command line.

Comment: Thanks for this info, but the Libs line in that file already contains every .so file in the library folder. Maybe its an obsolete function that is no longer compiled into the libraries, even though its still in the header file?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing?

You are putting libraries at the beginning of your link line, which is [wrong](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html). Move them to the end instead.

Comment: Fair enough. Ive updated the question to reflect the new order. The problem still exists.