# Issue executing OpenCV native functions via JNI

Tags: java, c++, opencv, java-native-interface, ubuntu-14.04

I'm attempting to run native OpenCV functions via the Java Native Interface on Ubuntu. Ultimately what I'm trying to accomplish is the use the `bagofwords` functions available in the default version of OpenCV, but for the time being I'm trying to test out running simple functions using this interface.

So, I have the following Java file with the relative native functions.

```
class OpenCVSample {

static {
    System.loadLibrary("Bridge1");
}

public native int BridgeFunction();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    OpenCVSample b = new OpenCVSample();
    b.BridgeFunction();
}

}
```

Here is my C++ `Bridge` file.

```
#include "OpenCVSample.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <cv.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_OpenCVSample_BridgeFunction(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {                             
IplImage *img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 640, 480 ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );                                               
    return 1;
}
int main(){}
```

Now as I mentioned, I'm doing this on Ubuntu, so I'm first compiling OpenCV into a shared library with the jdk with `gcc` with the following command.

```
g++ -shared -o libBridge1.so Bridge1.cpp -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -I/var/opencv/opencv/include/opencv 
-I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/core/include 
-I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/imgproc/include 
-I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/features2d/include 
-I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/flann/include 
-I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/calib3d/include 
-I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/objdetect/include 
-I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/legacy/include 
-I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/highgui/include
```

Which then create a shared library called `libBridge1.so`. Now the problem arises when I try to run the Java file itself, where I get the following error.

> java: symbol lookup error: /var/tests/oc/libBridge1.so: undefined symbol: cvCreateImage

I've looked into this quite a bit and I'm nearly sure I'm creating the shared library correctly, so can't understand why I'm getting this error, could anyone explain?

**-----------------------------------**
**EDIT**
**-----------------------------------**

Thanks to users Andrew Henle and James Black for the advise. I've gone ahead and linked the respective libraries with the following command.

```
g++ -shared -o libBridge1.so OpenCVSample.cpp -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -I/var/opencv/opencv/include -I/var/opencv/opencv/include/opencv -I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/core/include -I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/imgproc/include -I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/photo/include -I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/objdetect/include -L/var/opencv/opencv/build/lib -lopencv_core -L/var/opencv/opencv/build/lib -lopencv_imgproc -L/var/opencv/opencv/build/lib -lopencv_highgui -L/var/opencv/opencv/build/lib -lopencv_objdetect -L/var/opencv/opencv/build/lib -lopencv_features2d -L/var/opencv/opencv/build/lib -lopencv_video -L/var/opencv/opencv/build/lib -lopencv_core249
```

And the library seems to compile, however the issue now seems that the that it's filled with `undefined references`. When running the `ld` command on `libBridge1.so` i get the following stream of errors.

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_32s_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_16u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSub_8u_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32s_C1IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSum_32f_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_16u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16s_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_16s_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviXor_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_8u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_Inf_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_16u_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_32f_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_16s_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_8s_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSet_16u_C3MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `gzeof'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_32f_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16u_C3IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSum_16u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviAbsDiff_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L2_8u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviAbsDiff_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvsMinEvery_16u'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvMalloc'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_32f_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_16u_C3IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_8s32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_16s_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvsFlip_32f_I'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_16u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_8u_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16u_C1IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSub_16u_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSet_16u_C4MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_8u_C3IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_16u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `gzopen'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_32f_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_32f_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `gzclose'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_16u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviCompare_16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMax_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_16s_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_32f16u_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_32s32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_8u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_16s_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_32f_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L1_8u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_16u_C1IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L2_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `gzrewind'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_32s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviAdd_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_8u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_8u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSum_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_8s_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_16u32s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_16s_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_16u8s_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_16s_C4IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_16u_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L1_16u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviCompare_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMinMaxIndx_32f_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_32f_C4IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_32f_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSum_16s_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMin_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_16s_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `dlsym'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L2_16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviCopy_32s_C3MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_16u8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSet_16s_C4MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMax_16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMinMaxIndx_8u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `pthread_once'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L2_8s_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_32f_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_8u_C4IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_16s32s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviCopy_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvsMinEvery_8u'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvsFlip_64f_I'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvsMaxEvery_32f'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L1_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L2_32f_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_16u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviAdd_16u_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_16s_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_8u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_16u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMul_16u_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvsMaxEvery_64f'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_16u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32s_C4IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_8u_C3IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_32s8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16s_C3IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSum_8u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_Inf_32f_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_8u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMinMaxIndx_8s_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_32s16u_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_8s8u_C1Rs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_Inf_32f_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_8u_C1IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_8s_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_8u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvsSortAscend_8u_I'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_16u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_32f32s_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviCopy_32s_C4MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_8u_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_16u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSet_32s_C4MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_Inf_16u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_32f_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvInit'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_8u_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_8u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_32f_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_Inf_8u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_32s16s_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMul_16s_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_8s_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_16u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_StdDev_8u_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_32s_C4IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviCopy_16u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_StdDev_16u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L1_32f_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_32f8s_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSum_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_8u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_32s_C1IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMul_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_16s_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32s_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_32s8s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_16u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_Inf_16s_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32f_C4IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_8u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_16u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16s_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNot_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_Inf_8u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_16u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviLUTPalette_8u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_16u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32f_C1IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_Inf_16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_StdDev_16u_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSub_16s_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_Inf_32f_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_16u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviCopy_8u_C3MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_32s_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_16u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_8u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_Inf_16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_16s8s_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_Inf_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_8s_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L2_16u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMinMaxIndx_8s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_StdDev_8u_C3CR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSet_32f_C3MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_8s16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviAdd_8u_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_32f_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_16u16s_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSet_16s_C3MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSum_16u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_16s_C3IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_Inf_8s_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_8s16u_C1Rs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_32f_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_8u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviCopy_8u_C3P3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviCopy_16u_C3MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_8u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSum_8u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_32f_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16s_C4IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_8u_C1IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32f_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_StdDev_32f_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_16s_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_Inf_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSum_16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_16s_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_16u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviDotProd_16u64f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviCompare_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_StdDev_16u_C3CR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_8u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_8u_C4IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvsDotProd_64f'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSet_32f_C4MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvsMinEvery_32f'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_32f_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_8u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_Inf_16s_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSum_32f_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L1_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16u_C4IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_Inf_8u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSub_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMax_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_StdDev_8u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32f_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSum_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMinMaxIndx_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMin_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_8s_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSet_32s_C3MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_8s_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMax_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_32f_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_16u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_16u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_32f_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_32f_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviCopy_8u_C4P4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvsMaxEvery_16u'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_Inf_8s_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16s_C1IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviCopy_8u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSet_32s_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvsFlip_8u_I'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_8u32s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_Inf_8u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32s_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvsMinEvery_64f'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_8u16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviCopy_32s_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_8u8s_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviDotProd_16s64f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSet_16s_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_32f_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviOr_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_8u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32s_C3IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_16s_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_32f8u_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_16s32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMin_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviLUTPalette_8u_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `gzgets'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_32f_C1IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviAdd_16s_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_StdDev_32f_C3CR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_8u16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_StdDev_32f_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_32f_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_Inf_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMul_8u_C1RSfs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32f_C3IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMin_16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L2_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_32f_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_32s_C3IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_16s_C1IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_8u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_Inf_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_8u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_Inf_16u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L1_8s_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_32f_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_32f_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_32f_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `gzputs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_32f_C3IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviAbsDiff_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvsFlip_16u_I'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L1_16s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_16s16u_C1Rs'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvsDotProd_32f64f'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_StdDev_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMinMaxIndx_16u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_32f_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_16u32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_8u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvFree'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_Inf_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSet_32f_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMinMaxIndx_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvsMaxEvery_8u'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_8u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_16s_C3R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_8s_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_8u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMinMaxIndx_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `dlopen'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_16s_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L2_8u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_8u_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSum_16s_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_StdDev_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L1_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_16u_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviCompare_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_Inf_16u_C4R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L2_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_Inf_32f_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_16s8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_Inf_16u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviAnd_8u_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_8s32s_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormDiff_L1_16u_C3CMR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMean_StdDev_32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviConvert_8u32f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviSet_16u_C1MR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviDotProd_32s64f_C1R'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicviMirror_16u_C4IR'
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `ippicvsSortDescend_8u_I'
```

When running the java file itself, I now get this issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /var/tests/oc/libBridge1.so: /var/tests/oc/libBridge1.so: undefined symbol: ippicviMinMaxIndx_16u_C1R
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1855)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at Bridge1.<clinit>(OpenCVSample.java:4)
```

**---------------------------------**
**EDIT 2**
**---------------------------------**

After some further tinkering I've found the issue with getting undefined references. I was linking to the wrong core file. However the issue still persists, only on a smaller scale. Here is the following command I'm using:

```
 g++ -Wall -shared-libgcc -Im -o libBridge1.so Bridge1.cpp -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -I/var/opencv/opencv/include -I/var/opencv/opencv/include/opencv -I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/core/include -I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/imgproc/include -I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/photo/include -I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/objdetect/include -I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/include -I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/include -I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/highgui/include  -L/var/opencv/opencv/build/lib -lopencv_core249 -L/var/opencv/opencv/build/lib -lopencv_features2d -L/var/opencv/opencv/build/lib -lopencv_imgproc -I/var/opencv/opencv/build/lib
```

During the compile process I now get this error:

```
Bridge1.cpp: In function ‘jint Java_Bridge1_BridgeFunction(JNIEnv*, jobject)’:
Bridge1.cpp:8:12: warning: unused variable ‘img’ [-Wunused-variable]
  IplImage *img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 640, 480 ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
            ^
/tmp/ccqbVddx.o: In function `Java_Bridge1_BridgeFunction':
Bridge1.cpp:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to link your shared object with the required "-l..." options, just as if you were compiling a normal C/C++ executable to run that same function.

You should see the libraries needed if you do an "ldd libBridge1.so".  If you don't see the needed libraries, you need to add them to the link step.

Comment: But that's what I've done already if you take a look at the compile instruction eg: `-I/var/opencv/opencv/modules/core/include`. Also I ran `ldd` on the library, it just states that they are `statically linked`

Comment: Those are include directories, using the -I (upper case eye), not -l (lower case ell).  You need to add references to the link command for the shared objects your shared object needs in order to run - just like if it were an executable.  "-L/path/to/libs -lsomelib ...".  When it's correct, if you do "ldd -r libBridge1.so" you won't see any errors.

Comment: -I tells the compiler where your includes are, not where the libraries you need to link to are.   ldd will tell you libraries you link to, but you aren't linking to any.

Comment: I don't entirely understand how to go about this, I've never actually done anything with C++ previously. It's only the case now that I need to use a particular class that's not available in the OpenCV java port. Could you explain how I could do this?

Comment: What does the documentation for OpenCV say to use to link an executable to run?  The "-L" and "-l" (upper and lower case ell) options?  You need to add those to your gcc command:  gcc ... -L/path/to/libs -lOpenCV ... (assuming the library for OpenCV is called "libOpenCV.so")

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand, I didn't see your edited comment. I'll give this a go.

Comment: Also, see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415236/ububtu-opencv-and-linking

Comment: Hey, I gave this a shot, I've updated the main post with the result.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Andrew Henie about the `-l` flag, as I am curious how your library compiles.

But in your java class call `System.loadLibrary(..)` to load your library in the first place.

Then I expect it will fail, and using the `ld` command will be helpful to point out what you are missing.

Comment: Running `ld` returns the following. `ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
libBridge1.so: undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
`

Comment: And `ldd` just states that the file is `statically linked`

Comment: Hi James, I've updated the main post with updated results after linking the respective libraries.

Comment: Looks like you need to add `-ldl -lpthread` and the ippicv library, whatever that might be.