# OpenCV error: not able to link the opencv library files

Tags: c++, opencv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYDoy.png)

I have tried linking the libraries. But it didnt work out.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your command line does not link to any library

Comment: ***I have tried linking the libraries.*** Show the command you tried when you tried to link to libraries.

Comment: This answer should help: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/10420608/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10420608/487892)

Comment: Install OpenCV, then add `-lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui` to your command line.

Comment: BTW, it's against site policy to show a picture of your terminal / errors instead of just copying the text: [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: If you are using `VSCode` you likely need to edit your `tasks.json` to add these link arguments to the `args:` your command line looks like it was a VSCode task to me.